# Make ArrayList only show new data

Tags: java, android, arraylist, load

I have an app that shows images from an tumblr account. At the bottom of the list there is a "load more" button, when pressed loads 20 more images to the list. As it works now the app only appends to the new images to the list, so there is shown 40 images after the button has been pressed. How can i make it so the list only contains the new 20 images?

My code looks like this:

```
public class Example extends Activity {

static ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs;
Context context = null;
ListView listView = null;
TextView footer;
int offset = 0;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
public boolean isNew = false;

private String searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        tumblrs = getTumblrs();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
        footer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFoot);
        listView.addFooterView(v);
        listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem));

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    footer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new loadMoreListView().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tumblr> {

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int imageViewResourceId) {
        super(context, imageViewResourceId, tumblrs);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        Tumblr tumblr = tumblrs.get(position);
        if (tumblr != null) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            if (image != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(tumblr.image_url));
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                .getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Tumblr> getTumblrs() throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, JSONException {
    searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset=0";

    ArrayList<Tumblr> tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr>();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    try {
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray(
            "posts");
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("photos");
        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("url");

            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
            tumblrs.add(tumblr);
        }
    }
    return tumblrs;
}

public class Tumblr {

    public String image_url;

    public Tumblr(String url) {
        this.image_url = url;
    }
}

private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Example.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // increment current page
                offset += 2;

                // Next page request

                searchUrl = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/factsandchicks.com/posts?api_key=API_KEY&offset="
                        + offset;

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

                String responseBody = null;
                try {
                    responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);

                    JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response")
                            .getJSONArray("posts");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getJSONArray("photos");
                        for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
                            String url = photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes")
                                    .getJSONObject(0).getString("url");

                            Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
                            tumblrs.add(tumblr);

                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll
                // position
                int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                // Setting new scroll position
                listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Clear the list before adding the new instances?

Comment: By the way: You should not use "runOnUIThread" insinde "runInBackground" ... you can post intermediate results.

Comment: I just tried it without the runOnUIThread and without it i couldn't get the l"load more" button to work.

Comment: That's because you change a GUI-Element in there. You really need to have a look at the developer guides. You should not change a GUI-Element in doInBackground. There is a method to post results out of the doInBackground and a method to catch those. In that catcher you can then update your gui. See:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html Note `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinitialize the list like that (this adds a line in your `loadMoreListView#doInBackground` method).

```
tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr> ();
for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray photos = posts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("photos");
    for (int j = 0; j < photos.length(); j++) {
         JSONObject photo = photos.getJSONObject(j);
         String url =
             photo.getJSONArray("alt_sizes").getJSONObject(0).getString("url");
         Tumblr tumblr = new Tumblr(url);
         tumblrs.add(tumblr);
         }
}
```

PS: You have added way too much unneeded code.

Comment: When i try to add the line `tumblrs = ArrayList>Tumblr> ();` to my project is gives me an error "Expression expected after this token" isn't adding this line the only thing i should do? And i am aware that there is way to much code, i will clean it up soon.

Comment: tumblrs = new ArrayList<Tumblr> ();

Comment: @Fansher yes sorry I forgot the most important part - the `new` part.

Comment: Well, it works the first time the button is pressed, and then the button wont respond after that. Is there a logic reason for that?

Comment: No, it dose not log an error. The button just don't respond. It's not like the app crashes.

Comment: @Fansher as long as you catch errors it is not always the case that the app will crash in case of error.

Comment: No problem, i have solved the problem by setting the scrollposistion to 0. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, and I usually use this in my projects.

Just call `clear()` method on your `ArrayList` which goes into your `ArrayAdpater`.

Calling `clear()` on your `ArrayList` **before** loading it with the new data, will empty your previous data, and fill it with the new 20 entries.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
tumblrs.clear();
```

in your doInBackground() method